# delphi xe5 intalled package

Tags: java, android, delphi, delphi-xe5

i have this java code:

```
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
            ArrayList<String> mIdList=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(ResolveInfo mtemp:pkgAppsList){
                    mIdList.add(mtemp.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
            }
            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(mIdList.get(2));
            startActivity( LaunchIntent )
```

i'm trying to use this in delphi, but i don't know how to use Jlist(in delphi) istead of List < ResolveInfo > (java) because the result of the function "queryIntentActivities" is a JList.

```
var pm:JPackageManager;
intent:JIntent;
list:jlist;
rinfo:JResolveInfo;
begin
  pm:=SharedActivityContext.getPackageManager;
   intent:=TJIntent.JavaClass.getIntent(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
  intent:= intent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  list:=pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,TJPackageManager.JavaClass.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
 ShowMessage(IntToStr(list.size));

end;
```

How i can use Jlist associated with Jresolverinfo in delphi? because in java is declared like this: **List < ResolveInfo >** or how i can convert this `for(ResolveInfo mtemp:pkgAppsList)`
 in delphi

UPDATE: Also `the size of the list` is always 0 but it's not possible. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var
  PM: JPackageManager;
  mainIntent: JIntent;
  LaunchIntent: JIntent;
  pkgAppsList: JList;
  ri: JResolveInfo;
  iter: JIterator;
  midlist := TStringList;
begin
  PM := SharedActivityContext.getPackageManager;
  mainIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN, nil);
  mainIntent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  pkgAppsList := PM.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
  midlist := TStringList;
  iter := pkgAppsList.iterator;
  while iter.hasNext do
  begin
    ri := TJResolveInfo.Wrap((iter.next as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    mIdList.Add(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
  end;
  LaunchIntent := PM.getLaunchIntentForPackage(mIdList[2]);
  SharedActivityContext.startActivity( LaunchIntent )
end;
```